# FPDF create new pdf from another pdf with selected pages

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I have a pdf sample.pdf and i need to create a new pdf with pages 1,2,3,4 from sample.pdf.Is it possible using FPDF class .Please anyone help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is different about non-sample? New pages or change of extracted pages?

Comment: I need to create a new pdf with some pages extracted from sample.pdf